# Math Results Inaccurate PHP

Tags: php, mysql, math

Are there any rules to using math within PHP. I'm getting some off the wall numbers when I try to do some simple math.

Here is the specific script

```
            $profit = $quote_1 - $entry;
```

Here is a snippet of the full script

```
 if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
            $id = $row["id"];
            $symbol = $row["symbol"];
            $sym = strtoupper($sym);
            $entry = $row["entry"];     
            $exit = $row["exit"];   
            $openclosed = $row["openclosed"];       
            $entrydate = $row["entrydate"];
            $profit = $quote_1 - $entry;
            $color = "#000000";
            $positive = "";
            if ($profit >= 0){
                                $color = "#00a900";
                                $positive = "+";
                             } 
            else if ($profit < 0){
                                $color = "#ef3600";
                                $positive = "";}
            if(empty($symbol)) {
                                echo nothing;
                               }
                else {
                    $open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$symbol&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
                    $quote = fread($open, 1000);

                    fclose($open);

                    $quote = str_replace("\"", "", $quote);
                    $quote = explode(",", $quote);

                    $quote_0 = ($quote[0]);
                    $quote_1 = ((float)$quote[1]);
                    $quote_2 = ($quote[2]);
                    $quote_3 = ($quote[3]);
                    $quote_4 = ((float)$quote[4]);
                    $quote_5 = ((float)$quote[5]);
                    $quote_6 = ((float)$quote[6]);
                    $quote_7 = ((float)$quote[7]);
                    $quote_8 = ((float)$quote[8]);

                    echo "<ul><li><div class='wrapPicks'>
                  <div class='symbolPicks'>
                  <div class='quoteTitle'>$quote_0</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='bgPicks'>
                  <div class='quote'>Entry Price: $$entry</div>
                  <div class='quote'>Last trade: $$quote_1</div>
                    <!--<div class='quote'>Date: $quote_2</div>-->
                    <div class='quote'>Open P/L: <div class='bigGreen'><span style=\"color: $color\">$positive $$profit </span></div></div>
                   <!-- <div class='quote'>Change From Previous Close: $$quote_4</div>-->
                    <!--<div class='quote'>High: $$quote_6</div>
                    <div class='quote'>Low: $$quote_7</div>
                   <div class='quote'>Volume: $quote_8</div>-->
                   </div>
                    </div></li></ul>";
            }
```

Now something I thought of was that the yahoo data was coming in as a string possible and that may have been throwing things off. I'm also unclear as to whether my MYSQL table must be an int or is a VARChAR acceptable?

Comment: what math? PHP can do math just fine. More like, "is there any problem with my code?" You are using variable variables, so there's one major source of bugs.

Comment: You can determine how accurate the float numbers should be. Anyway I find your question too unclear to give an answer.

Comment: I see no math here. You're just echoing strings, and casting some of them to floats. No math.

Comment: Hire, I suggest putting a small, simple, self-contained test case that exhibits the problem, along with the results you expected it to produce, and the results it did produce. That example might be no more than two or three lines long, for a math issue. Definitely no reference to a database.

Comment: Hi Michael sorry about that. I always think of a one liner as something hard to understand without an external reference. Thats why I included the rest of the script. I also assumed that since I was grabbing stock data from yahoo it may have been the issue. This is the exact area for which the math is being done.

Comment: Sorry, but your edit is incomplete. What are the values of `$quote_1` and `$entry`, what result did `$profit` take, and what result did you expect it to take? By the way, I'll bet that once you put together a self-contained test case, you'll find it produces the results you expect. Then, expand the test case until you experience the problem again, and I'll bet you'll see the cause right away.

Comment: Ouch! I looked at the sample you provided, and that "math" is all over the place! Can you print out the raw values of the numbers in `$row`? You are using a variable `$quote_1` in `$profit = $quote_1 - $entry` but I don't see where it is defined...??? It's also not clear if you end up using database values, or yahoo quotes. Make the smallest self-contained example (so we don't need your database, etc) - as you do so you are likely to find your solution yourself.

Comment: $quote_1 is collected from Yahoo Floris. Thanks for your response.

Comment: What is the value of `$quote_1`? How does it get updated as you go around your loop? Are you using the value from the previous loop? That's what it looks like...

Comment: @Floris the value of $quote_1 is the last updated stock price from Yahoo

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta the value of quote_1 is the current price coming from yahoo and the $entry price is coming from my database. The separate single line in the original post is where I am trying to calculate current open P/L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
$open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$symbol&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
```

You need to substitute the actual symbol, not leave it as a string in the query. Maybe something like this:

```
$open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=".$symbol."&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
```

to concatenate the symbol will help.

If you have an invalid request, you are probably looking at garbage.

Also - you need to make this request before you do any math with it - in other words, you have to compute `quote_1` before you use the value to compute the profit.

Here is a ridiculously simplified version of what I am talking about. See if you understand why this is different than what you did, and how to get back "from here to there":

```
<?php
    $symbol = "GE";
    $entry = 23;
    $open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=".$symbol."&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
    $quote = fread($open, 1000);
    fclose($open);
    $quote = str_replace("\"", "", $quote);
    $quote = explode(",", $quote);
    $lastPrice = (float)$quote[1];
    $profit = $lastPrice - $entry;
    echo "current ".$symbol." quote: ".$lastPrice;
    echo "; entry: ".$entry."; profit: ".$profit;
?>
```

You can see this in action at http://www.floris.us/SO/stocks.php . I made no attempts at making it pretty - just getting the math right. Right now the output is

```
current GE quote: 23.32; entry: 23; profit: 0.32
```

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm not getting any invalid requests, but I am still receiving odd returns. quote_1 comes after it is known from the database that the symbol is what I need from yahoo.

Comment: OK - but you should not compute the profit until you have a valid quote!

Comment: I'm quite confused. Is there any way we can go into chat?

Comment: Sorry - I can't chat; firewall... Will try to update answer, give me a few minutes

Comment: Updated answer - hope it is clear now.

Comment: Fantastic Floris. I was able to understand what you meant by that snippet. Thanks so much for the help. I've been trying to figure this out all day! Thanks again! How would you say that in programming terms? Processing before?(For future reference)

Comment: I think programmers call it "assign a value before you use it". PHP allows you to use a variable (`quote_1`) before defining it - most (all?) compiled languages would throw a warning or even an error. Glad I was able to "put you back on track"!